# Puxar informações PHP via AJAX com jQuery em formato json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho um código em jQuery que realiza a criação de um calendário que dá para deixar lembretes na data. O código é o seguinte:

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        slotDuration: '00:15:00', /* If we want to split day time each 15minutes */
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        maxTime: '19:00:00',          
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: [
        {
            title: 'teste!',
            start: new Date(y, m, 3),
            className: 'bg-purple'
        }, 
        {
            title: 'teste 2!',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1),
            className: 'bg-red'
        }, 
        {
            title: 'See John',
            start: '2014-05-05 10:00:00',
            start: '2014-05-05 11:00:00',
            className: 'bg-red'
        }
        ],
```

A parte que realiza a criação dos lembretes é **"events:"** , Eu gostaria de puxar os eventos de uma página PHP e realizar o mesmo processo de criação de código como o do events, esse:

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'teste!',
        start: new Date(y, m, 3),
        className: 'bg-purple'
    },
```

Ou seja, eu tenho um PHP que tem um `echo` e nele tem o código acima, o jQuery tem que puxar e forma esse tipo de codigo. O problema é que não consigo fazer isso.

Comment: Procure por jQuery ajax, não entendo muito de ajax com jQuery então não vou dar uma resposta.

Comment: puxar com ajax até sei, mas preciso saber como formar o código daquele tipo com as devidas chaves e colchetes ([ e {)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se é pra gerar JSON, o PHP tem a função [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php):

```
$pessoa = array(
    "nome" => "Pessoa 1",
    "sobrenome" => "da Silva"
);

echo json_encode($pessoa); // Vai gerar {"nome":"Pessoa 1", "sobrenome":"da Silva"}

// Se vc quiser um array de pessoas ...

$pessoas = array(
    array("nome"=>"Pessoa 1", "sobrenome"=>"da Silva"),
    array("nome"=>"Pessoa 2", "sobrenome"=>"dos Santos"),
    array("nome"=>"Pessoa 3", "sobrenome"=>"dos Gists")
);

echo json_encode($pessoas);

/* vai gerar 
[
    {"nome":"Pessosa 1", "sobrenome":"da Silva"},
    {"nome":"Pessosa 2", "sobrenome":"dos Santos"},
    {"nome":"Pessosa 3", "sobrenome":"dos Gists"}
]
```

Comment: Mas retorna com **{** e **[** ?

Comment: sim, se seu array tiver índices não numéricos ele vai retornar um objeto { }, se só tiver índices numéricos inteiros, ele vai gerar um array [ ... ]

Comment: e caso tiver números e letras? como fazer para gerar { e [

Comment: Funciona, sim..

Comment: $arr = array('Palavra 1', 'a1d3', '8dz@');

echo json_encode($arr);

Com isso ele exibi [{palavra1, palavra2}] ... ?

Comment: Nesse caso aí ele retorna ["Palavra 1", "aid3", "8dz@"];

Comment: caso seu array seja $pessoa = array("nome"=>"Vagner", "email"=>"vluzrmos@gmail.com"); ela retorna {"nome":"Vagner","email":"vluzrmos@gmail.com"}

Comment: Então os [ ] eu tenho que adicionar manualmente?

Comment: veja o exemplo que fiz: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Vluzrmos/3f111cc78138668a46ca)

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou

Comment: Vagner, sugiro você incorporar as explicações extras e o código no Gist dentro da resposta, assim os próximos que virem este post não precisam ler todos comentários nem visitar outro site para entender.

Comment: Vlw @brasofilo, acabei de fazer isso, mas ainda não sei como deixar o código colorido ...

Comment: Estranho, as tags da pergunta deviam habilitar o realce de sintaxe... Mas pra forçar isso, confira http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33/201

Comment: O problema era o `<pre>` que não produz realce de sintaxe. Confira os detalhes do [markdown usado no Stack](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @brasofilo e após o usuário selecionar como pode ser enviado esses dados selecionado para o mysql . Fica o meu caso tem como vê http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181981/form-din%C3%A2mico-e-envio-para-o-mysql-via-jquery-e-ajax?noredirect=1#comment376494_181981

Answer (score 2):

Se o problema é só receber no js o que você está mandando do PHP, é só fazer uma chamada com $.ajax, passando a página PHP e o dataType: "json".

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/