# Form dinâmico e envio para o mysql via jquery e ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Já abrir algumas perguntas a respeito disso , fui ajudado , mas tipo da forma que falaram só serve se o form é normal , com inputs com name"alguma coisa aqui" o meu forme só tem um input"text" name"mesa" para colocar o número da mesa o restante da form vem via ajax do mysql . A minha duvida como posso passar esse form para o banco de dados  já que ele é dinâmico ?
Meu código abaixo.

Meu form

```
<div class="well">


                <!-- left -->
                <div id="theproducts" class="col-sm-5">
                </div>
                <!-- left -->
                <form method="post" action="relatorio.php" id="formRel">
                <span>Mesa</span>
         <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
                <input type="text" id="theinputsum">

                <!-- right -->
                <div id="thetotal" class="col-sm-7">
                   <h1 id="total"></h1>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Finalizar Pedido</button>
                </form>
                </div>
               <!-- right -->


            </div>
```

e o código javascript.

```
<script>
$('#formRel').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "relatorio.php",
  data: $("#formRel").serialize(),
  dataType : "html"
})
};
 </script>
```

a query de inserir está desse jeito.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "restaurant");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); exit;
$mesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
$pedido = $_POST['products'];
$preco = $_POST['products'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO spedido ('pedido','preco','numero_mesa') VALUES ('$mesa','$pedido','$preco')";

$link->query($sql);





?>
```

Obs : espero que não fiquem chateados por fazer uma pergunta simples pra vocês , mas que pra mim não está tão clara . já li a respeito de ajax mas todos os form eram normais , nenhum eram dinâmicas.

A imagem do meu form

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é uma questão de postar dúvidas simples, mas sim de criar 5 perguntas com o mesmo tema esperando ser ajudado ao invés de aproveitar a discussão em apenas uma delas.

Comment: conseguir até ter muitas respostas , mas todas eram voltadas para o form simples .

Comment: Nesse caso, se as respostas não atendem a sua necessidade, você continua a discussão e edita a pergunta, se necessário.

Comment: hum entendi , obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema pode ser resolvido utilizando o seletor correto para obter o valor do campo que você precisa. Para pegar por name você pode usar por exemplo:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=nomeAqui]")
```

Isso vai retornar um array com todos os inputs com o a atributo **name** igual *nomeAqui*.

Você pode ler mais sobre o querySelectorAll [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), nome que é possível utilizar outros tipos de seletores.

Já fiz um sistema parecido com o seu e resolvi atribuindo uma classe ao input, vou postar um snippet abaixo para você entender melhor.

```js
function calcular() {
  var elementValue = document.querySelector("input.mesa.ativa").value;
  document.getElementById("total").value = elementValue;
}
```

```css
input.mesa.ativa {
  border-color : #F00;  
}
```

```html
Mesa 1 : <input type="number" class="mesa" value=1 /><br>
Mesa 2 : <input type="number" class="mesa" value=2 /><br>
Mesa 3 : <input type="number" class="mesa" value=3 /><br>
Mesa 4 : <input type="number" class="mesa ativa" value=4 /><br>
Mesa 5 : <input type="number" class="mesa" value=5 /><br>
Mesa 6 : <input type="number" class="mesa" value=6 />

<hr>

<button onclick="calcular()">Pegar valor da mesa ativa</button>
<br>
<br>

Valor da mesa ativa: <input type="number" id="total" />
```

Com isso você pode ter uma base para resolver seu problema, selecionando os dados corretamente via javascript e enviando apenas o que você precisa para o servidor.